# Cross domain iframe resize fix without vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a website where I show information inside an iframe. And the information inside the iframe comes form Salesforce domain. The data that is being fetched comes in the form of a "training guide" with several pages in it.

I have added the javascript code on both the domains for fixing the changing height thus removing the Vertical scrollbar. Code in salesforce page:

```
  function retrieveInfo(){
          parent.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight, '*');
        }

        function showLoading(){
            $('#dvLoading').show();
        }
```

Code written in my website page is :

```
 function resizeCrossDomainIframe(id, other_domain) {
var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  var height = parseInt(event.data); // add some extra height to avoid scrollbar
  iframe.height = height + "px";
}, false);
```

}

and my iframe in the page is :

```
<iframe id="my_iframe" src="https://cp.secure.force.com/mydomainhome" width="100%"  onload="resizeCrossDomainIframe('my_iframe', 'https://cp.secure.force.com/');" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

The data inside the iframe has a left pane and a right pane. Left pane contains a list of collapsable menu that shows respective course contents. The left pane manu expands on clicking.The issue that I am getting is that the javascript code for removing V-scroll is getting called on page load but once the page loads and I click on the left pane to expand it the v-scroll reappears.

This is how the page renders on page load:
[image: This is how the page renders on page load:]

This is how the page renders after I expand the left pane menus with inner scrollbar:

[image]

Is there a way I can prevent the Vertical scrollbar appear even after expanding the left pane menu. I do not want to reload the page on clicking on each of the left pane menu links though.

Answer (score 0):

Would triggering the `retrieveInfo` on each window.resize event solve the issue?
By expanding the left menu, you are basically resizing the window of the iframe. If you repost your message, your iframe in the parent window will re-adjust accordingly.

I once solved this issue with an external library such as Iframe resizer (https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)
That might help you for browsers not supporting "postMessage".